# maven test behind proxy (squid)

Tags: java, junit, maven, jvm-arguments

I'm having a problem with Maven behind a squid proxy server.

I have a module of my system that depends external communication with a remote webservice.

I have my maven proxy configurations under ~/.m2/settings.xml, but apparently, these information are been used just for dependencies downloads.

When I run 'mvn test', these configurations aren't used on command line execution call. This is the instruction echoed on console:

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar /tmp/surefirebooter4156656684210940660.jar /tmp/surefire2646147996861949548tmp /tmp/surefire3498083351425809633tmp
```

There's a way to pass arguments to JVM during tests and other maven method executions?

Comment: have you simply tried setting http_proxy env variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix some arguments on `pom.xml`, we can configure `-DforkMode=never` directly on surefire plugin configuration. i.e.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-DforkMode=never</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The solution based on `-DforkMode` was suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824019/maven-2-1-0-not-passing-on-system-properties-to-java-virtual-machine), referenced by @johan-sjoberg on comments posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016508/maven-test-behind-proxy-squid/5016539#5016539)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this can be of interest to you: [How do I configure proxy settings for Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml). Alternatively you can try these startup parameters:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=url
-Dhttp.proxyPort=port
-Dhttp.proxyUser=user
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=pass
```

**[EDIT]**

These properties can also be set in `MAVEN_OPTS`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824019/maven-2-1-0-not-passing-on-system-properties-to-java-virtual-machine) describes how this would work for the test-profile.

Comment: I have thios configurations on my JRE jvmargs defined on Eclipse environment. But, MVN ignore this. The same applies to command line environment. How can I inject these jvmargs on mvn context, independently of runtime environment. Until now, dependencies are supported by ~/.m2/settings.xml. Each user have yours.

Comment: And [this](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) is what you're using? Have you tried setting the proxy information in `MAVEN_OPTS`? Also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824019/maven-2-1-0-not-passing-on-system-properties-to-java-virtual-machine) issue.

Comment: This is exactly the configuration defined on ~/.m2/settings.xml. I'll check MAVEN_OPTS and report here. Thanks by helping!

Comment: I used the argument explained on post that you suggested and it's working! Using "-DforkMode=never", i.e. 'mvn test -DforkMode=never', Surefire doesn't fork the execution from parent jvm process. Thanks! PS: how can I check your comment as Right Response?