# Maven exec with multiple system properties

Tags: java, maven, system-properties

I'm trying to run mvn exec with multiple system properties...it works ok with one but not with two for some reason.

e.g.
This works fine

```
mvn  -Dlocation=c:\tmp  exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="MyClass"
```

This doesn't work

```
mvn  -Dlocation=c:\tmp  -Djava.library.path=c:\zeromq\ exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="MyClass"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the solution proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/824025/1050015)?