# How to select indicated file from properties using maven

Tags: java, maven

I am using java in maven project for test automation.
I have two properties files:

- DEV.properties (environment: DEVELOPMENT)
- PROD.properties (environment: PRODUCTION)

I read this properties:

```
private static final Properties properties;
private static final String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILE = "DEV.properties";

static {
    properties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = Property.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILE);
    try {
        properties.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In "CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILE" variable I can indicate which environment I want to use (DEV or PROD).
How to do the same with a terminal using maven?
Something like:

```
 private static final String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILE = $environment;
```

and in terminal:

```
mvn clean test $environment=DEV.properties
```

or:

```
mvn clean test $environment=PROD.properties
```

Comment: `static final` is for indicating a _constant_ value. But your requirement is to have it _dynamic_. This isn't possible with constants.

Comment: Why do you need those different property files ? Apart from that you can't define the loading of a property file via environment variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

```
public class MyTest {
    private static final String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILE = System.getProperty("environment");

    static {
        var properties = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_PROPERTIES_FILE);
        try {
            properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you have to run `mvn` like in the below example because my assumption is that you run [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) in a forked mode which is a [default mode](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount).

```
mvn clean test -DargLine="-Denvironment=DEV.properties"
```

By using the [argLine](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argline) you can specify system properties that you want to pass to a forked JVM. Without the `argLine` those `-D` properties will not be passed from the so-called main (mvn) JVM to a child (forked) one used by the Surefire to run the tests.

For a bit of background on that "argLine" machinery you can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/824025/4886722) (and many others) or the [Maven mail thread](https://users.maven.apache.narkive.com/ldycVdRc/maven-2-1-0-not-passing-on-system-properties-to-java-virtual-machine). Both date back to 14 years ago...